# grab variable from url

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

i am new to php, but im trying. i need you guys help. 
i have the following url in the browser address bar www.dome.com\mypage.php?stu=12234342
i am trying to pass the url from the main page to the select case page call select.php
if i should echo the url i get www.dome.com\select.php. so i have decided to echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
instead, this gives me the correct url. how can i echo the variable from www.dome.com\mypage.php?stu=12234342 (12234342) 
unto select.php. select.php contains code that needs the $var stu=12234342 in order to display the correct message.

$request_url=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ; // takes the url from the browers
echo $request_url;

```
$cOption = $_GET['id'];

switch($cOption) {
    case 1:
    echo ' some text';
        break;
    case 2:
    echo ' this page.php';
        break;

    case 3:
    echo 'got it'; 
        break;
    default:
        echo 'Whoops, didn\'t understand that option: <i>'.$cOption.'</i>';
}
```

?>

Comment: You should also research XSS, as you have a vulnerability there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use parse_url() and parse_string() to grab the variable from a url:

```
<?php 

//assuming www.dome.com/mypage.php?stu=12234342;
  $url=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

//parse the url to get the query_string-part
  $parsed_url=parse_url($url);

//create variables from the query_string
  parse_str($parsed_url['query'], $unsafe_vars);

//use the variables
  echo $unsafe_vars['stu'];//outputs 12234342
?>
```

But note: you can't rely on the availability of HTTP_REFERER.

Comment: is this approach unsafe if yes, why?

Comment: variables coming from outside of PHP are always unsafe, for example the echoing of the variable will open doors for XSS

Answer (score 1):

try

```
echo $_GET['stu'];
```

on select.php

Comment: tried it and it came back as undefined, so i echo the url and got select.php. if i load the page separately nothing shows, its has if it's not seeing the url in the broswer

Comment: what is the version of your PHP installation? If its archaic :) then probably you have $HTTP_GET_VARS instead of $_GET.

Answer (score 1):

That's why you need to call the select.php file like this:
www.dome.com/**select.php?stu=12234342**

and then you can add:

```
echo $_GET['stu'];
```

By the way, you need to research about XSS, because that's a huge vulnerability.

Comment: XSS is indeed dangerous, but what has it to do with QUERY_STRING?! Isn't it related to Cookies mostly?

Comment: Not only for cookies, it's also related to RFI, and many more vulns that may affect for a simple misuse of the $_GET and $_POST vars, rule 1) Never trust user input. :)